# Where can I find data on Vegetarian Restaurants in the US?

Tags: data, united-states

I'm doing a GIS project on Vegetarianism and I'd like to include all of the vegetarian restaurants in the United States.  I haven't been able to find anything like it, or even data on all restaurants, vegetarian or no.  Does anyone know where I could look for it?

Comment: I'm sure there's data out there... don't you have MenuLog in the U.S. - it would also be in the white pages/yellow pages (if you have that there). The problem is you would be swamped with information and most of it not geolocated. Try Google, they seem to have a lot of data about all sorts of shops... it wouldn't be all, it wouldn't all be correct, but it's data nonetheless.

Comment: Our sister site [OpenData (Beta) SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) may be worth posting to on this one.  You may want to expand upon the fields you are looking for in any candidate data.  http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/list-of-all-restaurants-in-a-city-eu is a similar question on all restaurants in a European city

Answer (score 3):

A quick search for restaurant POI files turns this up: http://poidirectory.com/poifiles/united_states/restaurants/Vegan-US.html